# ActiveSupport notification from a specific object

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, notifications, activesupport

Is it possible to get an `ActiveSupport::Notifications` from a specific object? I have subscribed to SQL calls like this

```
ActiveSupport::Notifications.subscribe("sql.active_record") do |*args|
  event = ActiveSupport::Notifications::Event.new *args
  # check if event was from a specific object
end
```

but of course this triggers on EVERY SQL call system wide.

So I thought, maybe it's possible to only subscribe to events from a specific context. Or is it possible to check within the block which object was the originator?